# How to sql-recursive statements work?

Tags: sql, database, recursion, postgresql, statements

I am trying to understand sql recursive statements, but it is really hard for me. For example:

[image]

Thats an exampe I am trying to understand and to write down the output.

Can sb pls explain me how this works, step by step?

greetings and thx in advance

maya

Comment: There is a highly detailed set of three examples here: http://walkingoncoals.blogspot.com/2009/12/fun-with-recursive-sql-part-1.html  <shameless self-promotion>I also have [a blog post](http://adam-bernier.appspot.com/post/91001/recursive-sql-example) on the subject (specific to PostgreSQL).</shameless self-promotion>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, see here - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html, where the steps of the recursive query evaluation are described.

Answer (score 0):

The UNION ALL portion gets recursed until it returns no more records.  I don't know if you can have multiple UNION ALL portions.